# using OAuth2 for Google login

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, userid

I'm trying to identify users in Google Assistance.

I would like to use OAuth2 protocol, by implementing the Google login into my webapp, and then use the login details to verify the communication with Google assistance. However, I did not find identical details between Google account and Google Assistant.

How can we use the Google Login In to Access the Google Assistant?
 (something like user-id)?

Where could I find specific instructions?